# Threads not working

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

i am trying out the following code to learn threading in python.

```
import urllib.request
import re
import threading
from sys import argv, exit

if len(argv[1:])==0:
    exit("You haven't entered any arguments. Try again.")
else:
    comps=argv[1:]

def extr(comp):                     
    url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s='+comp
    req = urllib.request.Request(url)
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    respData = resp.read()
    print (re.findall(r'<span id="yfs_l84_[^.]*">(.*?)</span>',str(respData)))


for x in comps:
    t = threading.Thread(extr(x))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
```

I get the right result but one after the other and not at once. Am I missing something?

Comment: what result are you expecting?

Comment: @haifzhan The results don't come together, they come one at a time. My internet is a bit slow and I can tell

Comment: I think they might be executed parallelly but output does take somemilliseconds gap

Comment: @NikhilParmar The gap is in seconds actually. That is why I am thinking I might be doing something wrong

Comment: @BrendanAbel I am new to this sort of thing. I just adapted code from some sites

Comment: `t = threading.Thread(extr(x))` is the problem. You are calling `extr(x)`, and passing the *result* of that to the Thread constructor. Try `Thread(target=extr, args=(x,))`.

Comment: @TomDalton Not getting the result. How do I print the result?

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: Incidentally, printing from inside a thread should work fine, everything else being equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`t = threading.Thread(extr(x))` is the problem. You are calling `extr(x)`, and passing the result of that to the Thread constructor. Try `Thread(target=extr, args=(x,))`.

You'll then need to use something like https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html to allow threads to pass the result data back to the main thread before they terminate. You'd create the queue in the main thread, and pass it as an argument into each subthread.